# How can I see a string without newline characters with correct format in VS Code debuggin?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I want to debug my code (C#) in VS Code, I see that string values which have newline in them are shown in a non-legible format.

For example, this is what I see:

```
"\n            insert into DailyCounts (EntityTypeGuid, UtcDate, Count)\n            \n            select \n                'f4e46fc3-919c-11ed-878d-0242c0a82002',\n                date(UtcDate),\n                count(*)\n            from Social.Comments\n            \n            group by\n                'f4e46fc3-919c-11ed-878d-0242c0a82002',\n                date(UtcDate)\n        \n            on duplicate key update\n            Count=values(Count)\n        "
```

I want to see it in correct format like:

```
insert into DailyCounts (EntityTypeGuid, UtcDate, Count)

select 
    'f4e46fc3-919c-11ed-878d-0242c0a82002',
    date(UtcDate),
    count(*)
from Social.Comments

group by
    'f4e46fc3-919c-11ed-878d-0242c0a82002',
    date(UtcDate)
on duplicate key update
Count=values(Count)
```

How can I see strings as formatted when debugging in VS Code?

Answer (score 2):

Format specifiers can help with your problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp?view=vs-2022.

There is a specifier called `nq` (**no quote**) supported by offical C# debugger, and it can reverse escaped strings. You can see `json` and `json,nq` produce two different outputs in the picture below.

[image]

However, **WATCH** panel only shows the first line if you don't hover your mouse above the expression:

[image]